# Windows 10 Logging When A Window Opens or Closes

Tags: windows-10, logging, window

I've noticed a window that pops open and then immediately closes at random on my Windows 10 system. I haven't been able to figure out yet how to figure out what is causing that. My malware scans haven't turned anything up yet.

I've tried using the Event Viewer however the search fails to run for events that happen in the specified time period. Apparently the query is too long. How can I go about logging what processes open/close or what windows are created?

Thanks!

Comment: So why is this not visible in Event Logger at all? I appreciate that we are narrowing down what is causing this and how to disable it.

Comment: Is the window black, like command prompt screen?

Comment: Partly because I'm not sure where to look.

Comment: It didn't look like a command prompt screen. Maybe the animation just isn't letting the colour fill in before it disappears...

Comment: The solution of disabling the Microsoft Office Background Task Handler works. I want to understand, as in your original subject, why this pop up is not visible in Event Viewer. Is there somewhere we should look specifically to review these sort of millisecond pop ups?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Several other people have already asked that question during the last day. It's probably caused by Office.

See here:
[Console window keeps popping up](https://superuser.com/questions/1213475/console-window-keeps-popping-up)

Or this reddit discussion:
https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/6d8820/cmd_popups_with_an_hour_between/

Comment: Heh, and I thought I was the only one. Seems like Office is auto-updating in the background.

Comment: I looked up the event in the task scheduler and the window popped up right on time. Thanks for pointing this out to me.